# Tensorflow epochs are too slow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm trying to get started with **tensorflow** using the python interface. I'm building an image classification system explained [Here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification). But when running the code, epochs take too much time, almost 2 minutes for 1 epoch, and if number of steps are increased, epoch running time increases exponentially.
**My system configurations are:**

[image]

and software configurations are:

- Python 3.7
- Spyder 4
- Tensorflow 2.2.0

I found similar thread [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55335828/tensorflow-operations-are-unsusably-slow) but in my case, basic operations are fast enough.

**How can I improve performance of tensorflow**

Comment: You need a Nvidia GPU to accelerate training. There's no way around it as of today.

Comment: Two minutes per epoch sounds reasonable for the platform,I would not call this "slow"

Comment: @Dr. Snoopy read the documentation from given link, There are only 15 steps per epochs... Accordingly it is very slow

Comment: What is the comparison point?  The article does not say which platform it is using to obtain 8 seconds per epoch, so claiming 15 steps per epoch must be fast is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, both TensorFlow and PyTorch use only Cuda as a backend for GPU acceleration and they don't support any of the Mac'a GPUs - Intel's or AMD's. This means that your TensorFlow code would run only on CPU.